# Inserting date and datetime values in a Oracle and MSSQL compatible query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to perform an insert from a select that contains several date and datetime columns in code that is executed in both Oracle and MSSQL environments. Just the dialect is changed in the connection when switching environments.

I thought I could pass the Python `date` and `datetime` objects in, but that doesn't work.

The code below works in MSSQL but not Oracle. How can I generate vendor-agnostic code that achieves the same for both Oracle and MSSQL?

The code below is equivalent to what I am running with several unrelated fields removed for brevity.

```
timestamp = datetime.utcnow()
query = insert(MyModel).from_select(
    [
        MyModel.name,
        MyModel.date,
        MyModel.timestamp
    ],
    select(
        MyModel.name,
        cast(timestamp.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), Date),
        cast(timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), DateTime)
    ).where(
        MyModel.name == 'John'
    )
)
```

If I supply a `datetime` object directly, such as the case for the `MyModel.date` column shown below:

```
timestamp = datetime.utcnow()
query = insert(MyModel).from_select(
    [
        MyModel.name,
        MyModel.date,
        MyModel.timestamp
    ],
    select(
        MyModel.name,
        timestamp.today(),
        cast(timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), DateTime)
    ).where(
        MyModel.name == 'John'
    )
)
```

I receive the following exception:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Column expression or FROM clause expected, got datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 17, 0, 54, 57, 568623).
```

I have read the documentation for creating a column expression but I am not clear how to provide the value. It makes sense that a expression is more appropriate but I can't come up with one that works on both Oracle and mssql which is why I am simply passing the required value.

Comment: "doesn't work" is not an adequate description of the issue. Using generic Python `date` and `datetime` objects is the obvious approach, so please [edit] your question with a more complete description of how it "doesn't work". A [mcve] and complete stack traces would obviously be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the obvious way is to do it the same way you would in plain SQL, using a bind (either inline or externally to the query).

The following worked with both required dialects.

```
timestamp = datetime.utcnow()
query = insert(MyModel).from_select(
    [
        MyModel.name,
        MyModel.date,
        MyModel.timestamp
    ],
    select(
        MyModel.name,
        bindparam('date', timestamp.date(), type_=Date),
        bindparam('timestamp', timestamp, type_=DateTime)
    ).where(
        MyModel.name == 'John'
    )
)
```